# protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList has duplicated elements when objective-c & swift coexist

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

I'm using this to check the count of methods defined in a objective c protocol. And it was working fine.
But now, when we added some swift code (which uses the protocol in question), we notice that this method now returns duplicated entries.

Evidently there is something related to swift and objective-c generating different interfaces for the same protocol, or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example?